# Passing multiple values from popup in flex

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, popup

I,m able to send back a single value from custom SkinnablePopUpContainer but can't send back an Array with multiple values back to the view from which it is created ?

Any help in how I can do so ?

here's the code for the SkinnablePopUpContainer : I want to send back activityDetails Array

```
        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

        import valueObjects.Model;

        /* Variables */

        public var model:Model = new Model();
        private var selectCatStmt:SQLStatement;
        private var selectCatSQL:String = 'SELECT category FROM Activity GROUP BY category';
        private var activityStmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
        private var activitySQL:String = 'SELECT * FROM Activity WHERE category = :category';

        private var activityDetails:Array = [{category:'', activityId:0, hours:0}];  // I want to send this back to the view that creates this popup

        private function getCategories():void
        {
            selectCatStmt = new SQLStatement();
            selectCatStmt.sqlConnection = model.connection;
            selectCatStmt.text = selectCatSQL;
            selectCatStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
            selectCatStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
            selectCatStmt.execute();
        }

        private function selectResult(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            var result:SQLResult = selectCatStmt.getResult();

            if(result.complete)
            {
                if(result.data)
                {
                    categoriesList.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(result.data);
                }
            }   
        }

        private function errorHandler(event:SQLErrorEvent):void
        {
            trace ("\nError message: " + event.error.message);
            trace("\nDetails: " + event.error.details);
        }

        /* Event Handlers */

        protected function categoryList_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            selectCatStmt = new SQLStatement();
            activityStmt.sqlConnection = model.connection;
            activityStmt.text = activitySQL;
            activityStmt.parameters[":category"] = categoriesList.selectedItem.category;
            activityStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
            activityStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, activityResult);
            activityStmt.execute();
        }

        private function activityResult(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            var result:SQLResult = activityStmt.getResult();

            if(result.complete)
            {
                if(result.data)
                {
                    activitiesList.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(result.data);
                }
            }   
        }

        protected function addActButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            activityDetails[0]["category"] = categoriesList.selectedItem.category;
            activityDetails[0]["activityId"] = activitiesList.selectedItem.id;
            activityDetails[0]["hours"] = Number(duration.text);

            this.close(true,activityDetails);
        }

        protected function skinnablepopupcontainer1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getCategories();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
</s:layout>

<flextras:DropDownList id="categoriesList" labelField="category" width="100%" height="34" prompt="Select Type" change="categoryList_changeHandler(event)"/>
<s:List id="activitiesList" itemRenderer="renderers.ActivitiesList" width="100%" height="100%"/>
<s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="left" width="100%">
    <s:Label text="Activity duration in minutes : "/>
    <s:TextInput id="duration" width="50"/>
</s:HGroup>
<s:Button id="addActButton" label="Set" click="addActButton_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

here is popup close handler

```
        protected function activitySelect_closeHandler(event:PopUpEvent):void
        {
            if(!event.commit)
            {
                return;
            }

            activities.push(event.data);
            trace(activities);
        }
```

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: added the code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of the `close` method takes every data type "*". So it should not be an issue sending back an array or an object.

You'll need to listen for the `PopUp.CLOSE` event on the popup window. The `activityDetails` will be in the `data` property to the `PopUpEvent`.

Comment: I,m do use the close handler to handle the data but get an error, I have added the close handler at the end of my question.Ccan you see why it's causing an error ?

Comment: the error is Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: Error 1009 indicates that an object is null. Since I don't think the event object will be null, it must be the activities.

Comment: yes, that was the issue I forgot  to call constructor of the activities array ? It was missing the part after =
private var activities:Array = new Array();
never realized that arrays requirred this.

Comment: one more issue I,m getting data back from popup and able to see it only when I set event.data as activities ArrayCollection source. but get undefined when I use addItem on activities ArrayCollection.

Comment: Got it work instead of sending back and Array/ArrayCollection used object/valueObject.